# C# WPF - Print Web Page to PDF (using Microsoft Print to PDF Printer)

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, html-to-pdf

I've been struggling with what seems like a trivial problem for a couple of days now.
My app (C#, .NET6, WPF) creates an HTML output into a local folder on the hard disk. This is working perfectly.

What I'd like be to be able to automatically create a PDF from this. The "Microsoft Print to PDF" printer seems to produce a perfectly acceptable PDF (when I open the HTML file manually and manually print).

I get that I need to first render the HTML in order to get a PDF that doesn't just show the source markup from the HTML. So I thought of using a 'WebBrowser' control and then print the contents from there using 'PrintDocument', but it seems that the WPF WebBrowser control doesn't have a '.Print()' method like the WinForms version does.

It feels like I have all the bulding blocks, but I just can't put them together.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Use the native system to do HTML save as PDF that's as theoretically as simple as ONE SHELL LINE

```
msEdge.exe --headless --print-to-pdf="c:\wherever\filename.pdf "file:///myHTML.HTML"
```

the default location of edge III with Acrobat render, is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"`

the programming syntax is highly pedantic on "input.htm" and "output.pdf" must be "absolute" or else its likely to be blank. Also you may need other switches to add a delay, sometimes when required for the rendering (there are two that help).

to remove the printer footer and header **IT WAS** add in =old *--print-to-pdf-no-header* New 2023/24 syntax is aligned with Chromiums **`--no-pdf-header-footer`** also consider `--run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw` and you may need to adjust time for scripts to run using `--virtual-time-budget=1000` where start say with 5 or 6000 and reduce by half to fail then double that up again for that hardware.

[image]

```
>curl -o this.htm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76168410/c-sharp-wpf-print-web-page-to-pdf-using-microsoft-print-to-pdf-printer

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  141k    0  141k    0     0   374k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  376k

>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf="%cd%\demo.pdf" --print-to-pdf-no-header "file:///%cd%/this.htm"
>demo.pdf
>
```

P.S. you can actually run webview.exe --headless but its often fiddly with getting exact balance of --switches right, so use the reliable method of MS Edge, as it no longer needs other launcher wrappers, like it used to.

Comment: This is brilliant - thanks very much. Just implemented it. The output is much better than that using the nuget package I found for doing HTML-to-PDF conversation, presumably because Edge can render the HTML much better. Issue was that I'm generating some SVG Graphics on-the-fly, these look exactly as I expect them in the PDF when using Edge to do the rendering... thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of paid options for this, but there is also this library:

https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer

It hasn't been updated for some time, but that doesn't mean it doesn't work.

Notice though that it does mention in the readme:
*Extensive HTML 4.01 and CSS level 2 specifications support*

So your HTML would need to be limited to that spec.

Comment: What are some of the paid options you mention?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer by K J, since StackOverflow won't let me add a comment.

To remove headers and footer, use the following option:
--no-pdf-header-footer

This other option is deprecated and does not work:
--print-to-pdf-no-header

You can alternately use this line in your style:
@page{ margin:8mm;}